# Laravel 5.1 - Pass variable from ajax to my controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

i have a list of comments with ajax but it doesnt work:

CommentList.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var tablaDatos = $("#comentos");
        var dato2= $("#article_id").val();
        var route = "http://localhost:8000/commentList/"+dato2;

        $.get(route, function(res){

            $(res).each(function(key,value){
                tablaDatos.append(value);

            });
        });

    });
```

article.blade.php

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <li id="comentos">
       <input type="hidden" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="{{$article->id}}">
   </li>
@endforeach
```

FrontController.php

```
public function listing($id)
    {
        // store the comments list
        $list = [];

        // retrieve comments
        $article = Article::where('article_id', $id)->first();
        $comments = Comment::where('article_id', $article->id)->get();

        // render each comment and store it
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            $html = view('layouts.comment-template')
                ->with('comment', $comment)
                ->render();

            $list[] = $html;
        }

        // return a JSON array of the comments list
        return response()->json($list);

    }
```

> I passed "$article" to my view "article.blade.php", so "$article->id" work well

I think that problem is that $article->id input doesnt pass to my controller, maybe a problem with commentList.js ( wrong route?)

Route

```
Route::get('commentList/{id}','FrontController@listing');
```

There is a best way to pass my variable id?

Comment: What response are you getting in your console? "It doesn't work" isn't enough, if you are doing an ajax request the server should send something back that is indicative of the kind of issue you are having.

Comment: oh i check my console, and the error is Article::where('article_id' , $id), the correct is Article::where('id', $id).

Answer (score 0):

oh i check my console, and the error is Article::where('article_id' , $id), the correct is Article::where('id', $id).